# Define a bson Object on Android

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb

i'm working in an android app,I have to select data from mongoDB using their id. the id is an bson object. how ca i define a bson object on android???
(i'm using nodejs to connect the android app to mongodb)

Comment: [`org.mongodb.bson`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/bson/2.3) dependency perhaps! That would seem to the logical thing to do, do you not think? Note that it's likely your API is simply sending a "string" value, but you can cast to the type if you so wish.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work:   

Gradle sync failed: Supplied String module notation 'org.mongodb.bson ' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.


   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)




Gradle sync failed: Supplied String module notation 'org.mongodb.bson ' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.
   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: What does not work? There is no code in your question at all to show what you are trying to do. Are we supposed to guess? You need to be a lot more specific here. And [**Edit your Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45453851/edit). The comments section is for people like me asking you "what are you talking about?" The question is where **you** explain it.

Comment: String json=JSON.serialize(id2);
        final DBObject idb=(DBObject)JSON.parse(json);

Comment: You're using Node.js inside Android??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send `id` as a `string` simply you can generate bson object as below,

```
BasicOutputBuffer output = new BasicOutputBuffer();
    BsonBinaryWriter writer = new BsonBinaryWriter(output);
    writer.writeStartDocument();
    writer.writeName("id");
    writer.writeString("1");
    writer.writeEndDocument();

    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), output.getInternalBuffer());
```

Remember to add `writeStartDocument();` and `writeEndDocument();`